# Methods of Matlab's Built-in Objects

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

What are the differences between these two calling sequences **get(a) and a.get()**?

```
load gong
a = audioplayer(y, Fs);
a.get
get(a)
```

Comment: Nothing, take a look [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/create-a-simple-class.html), section 'Call Methods'.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference *by default*. However, the behavior can be modified.

By default, for an object of a custom class, `obj.method(arg1,arg2,...)` is syntactic sugar for `method(obj,arg1,arg2,...)`. This means that when you write the former, MATLAB pretends you wrote the latter and proceeds accordingly.

However, it is possible to overload the method [`subsref`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) for the class, in which case this function will be called for the syntax `obj.method(arg1,arg2,...)`. That is, MATLAB interprets it as an indexing operation (`.method`) followed by another indexing operation (`(arg1,arg2,...)`). The `subsref` method is called to evaluate these indexing operations. It is possible to implement it such that the appropriate method is called in this case, but custom indexing code is executed for other indexing operations such as `obj(x)` or `obj{x}`. See for example [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/code-patterns-for-subsref-and-subsasgn-methods.html).